# How Do You Make Changes To A WordPress Theme That Uses Grunt For JS Files?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gruntjs

I am trying to makes changes to a JS file in a WordPress theme I am using. The theme uses Grunt to package all the CSS and JS files. I have never used Grunt before so I'm wondering how I can update some of the JS files.

Is there a simple way to do this?

From my research online it seems I need to install a package to my server — is this correct? Any directions or help is much appreciated. I've pasted below the Grunt.js file that the theme uses.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'js/vendor-min.js': [
                        'js/jquery.mixitup.js',
                        'js/jquery.stapel.js',
                        'js/owl.carousel.js',
                        'js/jquery.magnific-popup.js',
                        'js/modals.js',
                        'js/auth.js',
                        'js/jquery.mousewheel.js',
                        'js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js',
                        'js/placeholder.js',
                        'extensions/mail_subscription/js/mail_subscription.js',
                        'js/plugins.js',
                        'js/theme.js'

                    ],
                    'js/widgets/min/jflickrfeed.min.js': [
                        'js/widgets/jquery.jflickrfeed.js'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: [
                    'js/*.js',
                    'extensions/mail_subscription/js/*.js'
                ],
                tasks: ['uglify']
            },
            styles: {
                files: [
                    '**/*.scss'
                ],
                tasks: ['compass']
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            files: [
                'js/theme.js'
            ],
            options: {
                globals: {
                    jQuery: true
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

};
```

Comment: have you run `npm install` in the project directory?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with using Grunt. All I did was purchase the theme, installed it and now I want to make JS changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you need to install the dependencies of the project first, then you can use the Grunt task to compile assets. You will need [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and [Grunt-cli](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli) (`npm install -g grunt-cli`) installed.

1. `cd` into the theme directory
2. Run `npm install` (this will install all the dependencies of the theme)
3. Run `grunt watch` (this will start grunt watching the files for changes)
4. Edit JS/CSS files whilst the `grunt watch` task is running, and when you save you should see the JS/CSS recompiled

If you don't wish to have `grunt watch` running all the time, you can manually run the `grunt uglify`, `grunt jshint` and `grunt compass` tasks individually.